# i am having a insertion issue in mysql using nodejs

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

```
Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'username' cannot be null
code: 'ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR',
  errno: 1048,
  sqlMessage: "Column 'username' cannot be null",
  sqlState: '23000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'insert into loginuser (username, email, password) values (NULL,NULL,NULL)'
```

this is my sevices code i cannot insert my data in the database kindly look into it and help in resolving the issue

```
module.exports = {
    create: (data, callback) => {
        pool.query(
            "insert into loginuser (username, email, password) values (?,?,?)",
            [
                data.username,
                data.email,
                data.password
            ],
            (error, results, fieds) => {
                if(error){
                    return callback(error)
                }
                return callback(null, results)
            }
        );
    }
```

Comment: It seems like you `data` has no values set

Answer (score 0):

Please check in phpMyadmin in your table STRUCTURE and allow NULL value for specific column in which you want to enter null if no value is passed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X67a.png Check this Image.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).